# Como borrar código innecesario de interfaz gráfica en visual studio code c#

Tags: interfaz-gráfica, visual-studio-2019

Buen día! Soy nuevo utilizando Visual Studio para interfaces gráficas. Cada que se le da doble click a un icono de interfaz, se genera un metodo. Lo que pasa es que he dado doble click en iconos que yo no necesito generar código, y me preguntaba como puedo borrar esa parte del código, ya que al borrarla, me da un error. Esto más que nada para hacer un código más limpio.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PIA_Interfases
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int posX = 0, posY = 0;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ///////////////BORRAR///////////////////
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //Boton para cerrar la ventana
    private void bunifuImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
    //Boton para minimizar la ventana
    private void minimizarButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }

    //Evento activado cuando el mouse es precionado
    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            posX = e.X;
            posY = e.Y;
        }
        else
        {
            Left = Left + (e.X - posX);
            Top = Top + (e.Y - posY);
        }
    }

    private void panel1_DockChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ///////////////BORRAR////////////////////////
    }

    //Evento para cambiar la posición del formulario
    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        ///////////////BORRAR////////////////////////
    }
    //Evento para cuando el mouse se suelta
    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ///////////////BORRAR////////////////////////
    }
}
```

}

Tengo la intención de borrar los metodos en los que he escrito borrar pero cuando lo hago simplemente eliminandolos del codigo, me aparece el siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! vs code no es lo mismo vs 2019.. son dos ide totalmente distintas... si estas usando winforms, tenes que eliminar los eventos de cada control... si es wpf, tenes que eliminarlos del xalm...

Answer (score 0):

sé que ya ha pasado tiempo desde que realizaste tu pregunta, pero igual la contesto por si después alguien necesita ayuda.

Cuando das doble click sobre un (por ejemplo) botón, se genera un metodo en form.cs y también el handler en form.Designer.cs

[image: form.Designer.cs]

Lo que hay que hacer, es entrar en form.Designer.cs y buscar el Handler del evento Click (en caso de ser un botón) y eliminar la linea:

```
this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y listo!